# Catch img who are within a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my page:

```
$('img[title!=""]').each(function() {
```

It currently selects the all `img`'s in the website, but I only want to get the images that are within a certain div called 'layout' where title is not null, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `layout` is ID of div

Use

```
$('img[title!=""]', '#layout').each(function() {
```

OR

```
$('#layout img[title!=""]').each(function() {
```

Comment: +1. I would add that if you already have `#layout` selected and stored in a variable (DOM or jquery) that is when the first form really shines as you can do `$('img[title!=""]', layoutElement)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myDiv").find('img[title!=""]').each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

That would catch all `<img>` in `#myDiv`:

```
<div id="myDiv">
      <img src=" ... />
      <img src=" ... />
      <img src=" ... />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jw8sc/)</kbd>

First, you might need to allow for those elements that don't have a title attribute at all.  This condition would be covered by:

```
$('#layout img[title]').each(function() {
```

However, then you must check if the title attribute is present but blank:

```
if ( this.title != "" )
```

Putting it together:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="layout">
    <img title="kitten01" src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/151/151" />
    <img title="" src="http://placekitten.com/152/152" />
    <img title="kitten04" src="http://placekitten.com/153/153" />
</div>
<div id="otherdiv">
    <img title="dog01" src="http://placedog.com/150/150" />
    <img title="dog02" src="http://placedog.com/150/150" />
    <img title="dog03" src="http://placedog.com/150/150" />
</div>
```

**jQuery/js:**

```
$('#layout img[title]').each(function() {
    if ( this.title != "" )
    alert( this.title );
});
```

---

Note: you may already know this, but fwiw the above example assumes that your div is called `layout` because it has an ID attribute named layout.  If the div is of `class="layout"` then:

```
$('.layout img[title]').each(function() {
```